# How do I detect enter key hit on NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, swift2

In a text field, I need to detect user hit Enter (return) key. The delegate methods are completely different from the ones in UITextField so not really sure what to do ... I use swift 2.3 atm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the user hits the <kbd>enter</kbd> key the delegate method

```
func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ aNotification : Notification)
```

is called.

This is the Swift 3 syntax. Type `cont` and use code completion to get the Swift 2 syntax.

Comment: But it will also be called when user tap on other views - any better way to only detect enter?

Comment: The notification passes additional information to distinguish the reason of the call.

Comment: How do I parse it out to check whether it's from the enter key?

Comment: @user3064009 Yes, please check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontroltexteditingdelegate/3005178-controltextdidendediting)